# Cartoon identification: robots in a dark future, protagonist has a cane-like robot

Tags: story-identification, robots, cartoon

So, this is a late 90's early 2000 cartoon.

Set in a dystopian future. We have an evil government that uses robots to control people.

Even if set in future, the people kind of live in a medieval/simple way.

Protagonist is a blond guy, hair on shoulders.

*The great differential is that he has a robotic companion that looks like a cane, just a sphere head with a lantern eye and an rod coming out of it. It could be inserted on other robots or machines and interact with them, like R2D2 does.*

[image: Robot is like this]

Art style is like Heavy Metal or Titan movie. 2d draws with some cg.
Colors used are darkish. It was a series, not a movie.

Comment: +1 for the picture. We need more pictures like that.

Comment: Hand-drawn pictures > hand-drawn circles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Xyber 9: New Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xyber_9:_New_Dawn) .

> Jack, a precocious, blonde fifteen-year-old who is an orphan, is given the title of the Chosen One. The people of Terrana, a futuristic realm that has is amidst a war, relies upon him as the last hope to save their civilization. If Jack can achieve the Herculean task of destroying Machestro, the evil ruler of the underworld, he will be named king. Jack's greatest weapon against Machestro is the sophisticated computer Xyber 9 that is in the form of a staff. With Xyber 9's power, Jack journeys through Machestro's underworld and to other futuristic lands, fighting intergalactic evil with an ever-increasing band of allies. In order to enfeeble the Chosen One, Machestro tries desperately to snare Xyber 9, for without the powerful computer, Jack would be defenseless. And with it, Machestro could spread his disease of evil throughout Terrana and beyond, conquering other worlds and ruling in his tyranny.

[image: Jack and Xyber 9]